# two datagrid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-3.0

There is two tables in database. Tables is related with foreign key.
table 1 --> datagrid 1
table 2 --> datagrid 2
datagrid 1 items is selected, Datagrid 2 shows table_2 datas.

Comment: You need to add more detail and ask a question; otherwise, you run the risk of not getting this answered or even having the question closed as "Not a real question".

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you use Tag propery in you rows and use binding:

datagrid1.SelectedItem.Tag --------to-------> datagrid2.ItemsSource.

At thefirst datagrid set array of objects with property Tab ( with type Object ) and during them getting make query to database and return the datagrid (or inherit from them).

Don`t forget cache query ;)